# Find state from country and city in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am having the country and city columns in my file. I am looking to see the sales city wise but when I try to use the filter in geolocation type tableau is not showing them. attaching below the city wise bar plot. I need the same to be shown in geolocation view.

Map and city wise bar chart images

[image: Map and city wise bar chart images]

Answer (score 0):

Tableau will need more from your dataset in order to find the State. If there are only city and country columns, Tableau will not know which state you're referencing. There are many states that have similar city names (ex. Jackson, MS, Jackson, GA, and Jackson, TN).

Adding a zip code to the data set should allow Tableau to find the state as well.

Comment: Though adding an extra field containing *state* to the hierarchy of locations would be better.

Comment: The more the merrier!